# Trouble with the HTML() function in Golang's "html/template" package

Tags: html, templates, go

I am having an issue with getting the `"html/template"` package to parse a template properly. I am trying to parse in HTML content to a template page that I have made, however, when I try, the parsed page ends up with the escaped HTML instead of the actual code I want.

[The Go documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#hdr-Typed_Strings) says I can simply use the `HTML()` function to convert a string into a `type HTML`, which is known to be safe and should be parsed in as HTML. I have made my `Content` field in my `type Page` a `template.HTML`, which compiles just fine, but when I use the `template.HTML(content)` function in line 53, I get a compiler error saying:

`template.HTML undefined (type *"html/template".Template has no field or method HTML)`

Using `HTML(content)` (without the preceding `template.`) results in this error:

`undefined: HTML`

My end goal is to have other HTML files parse into `index.html` and be interpreted by the browser as HTML.

Any help is appreciated.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func staticServe() {
    http.Handle(
        "/assets/",
        http.StripPrefix(
            "/assets/",
            http.FileServer(http.Dir("assets")),
        ),
    )
}

var validPath = regexp.MustCompile("^/(|maps|documents|residents|about|source)?/$")


//  This shit is messy. Clean it up.

func servePage(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    type Page struct {
        Title   string
        Content template.HTML
    }

    pathCheck := validPath.FindStringSubmatch(req.URL.Path)
    path := pathCheck[1]
    fmt.Println(path)

    if path == "" {
        path = "home"
    }

    template, err := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    contentByte, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path + ".html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    content := string(contentByte)

    page := Page{strings.Title(path) + " - Tucker Hills Estates", template.HTML(content)}

    template.Execute(res, page)
}

//  Seriously. Goddamn.

func serveSource(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    sourceByte, err := ioutil.ReadFile("server.go")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    source := string(sourceByte)
    io.WriteString(res, source)
}

func main() {
    go staticServe()
    http.HandleFunc("/", servePage)
    http.HandleFunc("/source/", serveSource)
    http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having imported "html/template" earlier, this line

```
template, err := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
```

shadows the template package, so when you do `template.HTML` later on, you're looking for `HTML` attribute on the template object, not for something called `HTML` in the package.

To prevent this, change the name of your variable.

```
tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
```

Comment: Ahh. See, that's the kind of thind I would never think of. Thank you so much, I'll report back soon on how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are shadowing your package with a variable called template. The easiest fix is probably to change your variable name to tmpl or something.